# Why I should not depend on HttpResponseBase.statusText in Angular

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I have a httpInterceptor in Angular which catches error responses sent from my ASP.NET WebAPI backend and check whether it is an expired token response. If yes, a token refresh call to API will be fired. this part looks like below:

```
if (error.status === 401) {
     if (error.statusText === 'invalid_token' || error.statusText === 'unauthorized') {
         // navigate user out
     } else if (error.statusText === 'expired_token') {
         // refresh token
     } else {
         // something else..
     }
}
```

I am checking the `statusText` field besides status code 401 in the error response to see whether it says 'expired_token' which is the value I set in my API. It looks like this:

```
var errorresponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
{
  Content = new StringContent("expired_token"),
  ReasonPhrase = "expired_token"
};
```

It worked fine until I switched to a new PC and reinstalled everything. (including Angular, VS2017, iisexpress etc.) All of a sudden the `statusText` field I receive in the error responses are no longer saying 'expired_token'. Instead, it always return 'OK' which I believe is the default value. Looks like I have to use 'error' field to do my checks which carries the same message.

But this issue did make me curious. So I dug deeper in the issue. In Angular's document of [HttpResponseBase](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponseBase) class, on `statusText` property it says 'do not depend on this'. But the document does not mention what does that mean exactly. Can anyone help me explain why I should not depend on the `statusText` property, or why will its "expired_token" value cannot be picked up anymore in my client side?

Comment: Check to make sure the project is the correct version. this sounds like the project asp.net-code updated to core which serializes `HttpResponseMessage` and returns 200 OK as it is no longer a first class citizen in the pipeline. It treats it like a model.

Comment: You'd better check what object is your service getting? And checking its detail is preferred. See https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse If it is a HttpErrorResponse, last comment of 'ok' will be hilarious to all.

Comment: Because HTTP protocol only defines what status codes should be, but it does not restrict on the status text. Web servers/devices can return any text they like, so you cannot assume the value is fixed.

Comment: @wannadream good point and I did check the ok field. The value is false in my scenario. So 'OK' only appears in 'statusText' field

Comment: @LexLi Thanks, it makes sense.